# How do you get proper Material 3 behavior out of NavigationBar?

Tags: flutter, navigationbar, back-button, material3

I am instantiating a `NavigationBar` but navigating from a tab's base page to a detail page within (drilling down from a summary to detail) makes the detail go full screen instead of remain within the tab's restricted space (the 90% of the screen above the tab bar). Material has dictated this behavior for years. I have seen many work-arounds out there but I can't believe that Google is so sloppy as to leave this unaddressed.

I would assume there is a flag akin to `useMaterial3` that could be provided to `NavigationBar` to make it behavior properly, but I've not been able to find anything of the sort. Does someone know how to make this widget behave in the updated Material fashion?

```
class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  int currentIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: NavigationBar(
        onDestinationSelected: (int index) {
          setState(() {
            currentIndex = index;
          });
        },
        selectedIndex: currentIndex,
        destinations: const <Widget>[
          NavigationDestination(icon: Icon(Icons.home), label: "Page 1"),
          NavigationDestination(icon: Icon(Icons.person), label: "Page 2"),
        ],
      ),
      body: <Widget>[
        const Page1(),
        const Page2(),
      ][currentIndex],
    );
  }
}
```

I implemented a work-around to simulate the correct behavior, but it clashes with trying to implement `CupertinoPageTransitions` in order to get swipe-back functionality (which requires use of `Navigator` when drilling into that detail page). So I'd really love to know how to make the actual Google-created widget behave as Google claims it should.

```
class _TabState extends State<Tab> {
  int _index = 0;
  final List<Map> _detail = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: IndexedStack(
        index: _index,
        children: [
          SummaryWidget(onTap: showDetail),
          for (final data in _detail) DetailWidget(id: id, onClose: removeDetail);
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
  
  showDetail() {
    setState(() {
      _detail.add(data);
      _index = 1;
    });
  }

  removeDetail() {
    setState(() {
      _index = 0;
      _detail.removeLast();
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you provided `userMaterial3: true` in `ThemeData` while wrapping with `MaterialApp`?

Comment: @ShahedEmon yes, that does not affect the nav bar behavior as far as I can tell